# How to CREATE TABLE with unique constraint on two columns using UCanAccess?

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

How to write sql query to create table with unique constraint on 2 columns using jdbc:
I try this code and give me  "SQLException: Invalid create statement!":

```
 Connection conn = ConnectDB.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
            String sql = "CREATE TABLE TBL_fonts" +
                    + "(char_id int not NULL, "
                    + "FW VARCHAR(255), "
                    + "code VARCHAR(255), "
                    + "character VARCHAR(255), "
                    + "CONSTRAINT fontConst UNIQUE(FW,code), "
                    + "PRIMARY KEY (char_id))";
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        conn.commit();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: please include the stacktrace

Comment: SQL working fine in MS-sqlserver, post your stack trace, that may help finding what's wrog

Comment: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid create statement.
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.addDDLCommand(AbstractExecute.java:103)
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.AbstractExecute.executeBase(AbstractExecute.java:119)
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.ExecuteUpdate.execute(ExecuteUpdate.java:56)
 at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeUpdate(UcanaccessStatement.java:160)

Comment: try - add unique index(column1, column2);

Comment: give me: UcanaccessSQLException: unexpected token: INDEX required: (

Comment: Isn't the problem with your definition of the primary key instead? AFAIK that should be `CONSTRAINT <name> PRIMARY KEY (char_id)` as well.

Answer (score 3):

This issue has been fixed in UCanAccess 2.0.6.2. The code

```java
String sql = 
        "CREATE TABLE TBL_fonts ("
        + "char_id int not NULL, "
        + "FW VARCHAR(255), "
        + "code VARCHAR(255), "
        + "character VARCHAR(255), "
        + "CONSTRAINT fontConst UNIQUE(FW,code), "
        + "PRIMARY KEY (char_id)"
        + ")";
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```

now works as expected.